# Not getting the mongo documents within the given epoch timestamp

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a mongodb collection in which I am storing transaction epoch timestamp, one of the document looks like this:

```
{
   "customer_transaction_date_timestamp" : NumberInt(1693784771),
   "customerTransactionDate": "03092023234611" //ddMMyyyyHHmmss
}
```

now I am trying to get all the documents between the date `03-09-2023 00:00:00` and `04:09-2023 00:00:00`.
To achieve this I am getting the above dates epoch timestamp and then running the following  query

```
{ "customer_transaction_date_timestamp" : { "$gte" : 1693679400, "$lt" : 1693765800}}
```

The `1693679400` is the epoch time for `03-09-2023 00:00:00` and `1693765800` is the epoch time for `04:09-2023 00:00:00`

But the above query doesn't return the document with these details

```
{"customer_transaction_date_timestamp" : NumberInt(1693784771),
   "customerTransactionDate": "03092023234611" //ddMMyyyyHHmmss
}
```

even though the date is `03-09-2023 23:46:11`

Comment: `1693784771` is greater than `1693765800`, thus your document is not in range

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to save your timestamp like this, you can query:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {$and: [
      {$gte: [
          "$customer_transaction_date_timestamp",
          {$divide: [{$toLong: ISODate("2023-09-03T00:00:00.000Z")}, 1000]}
      ]},
      {$lte: [
          "$customer_transaction_date_timestamp",
          {$divide: [{$toLong: ISODate("2023-09-04T00:00:00.000Z")}, 1000]}
      ]}
  ]}
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UlnwK3JQeet)

But I suggest you save it as `ISODate`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "customer_transaction_date_timestamp": {
    $gte: ISODate("2023-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    $lt: ISODate("2023-09-04T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_R1rTvyhcSJ)

Comment: Hi, I am using java to store the data the date but I am unable to store ISODate format that is why I sticked to the epoch time

Comment: You should find the way to store it as `ISODate` as this is the common practice. On `nodejs` you can do: `customer_transaction_date_timestamp: new Date()`. I'm sure on `java` there is a similar common practice.